# data directory was initialized by PostgreSQL version 13, which is not compatible with this version 14.0

Tags: postgresql, docker, debian, portainer

I have downloaded Portainer onto my server and created a PostgreSQL database in a container there.
Today I could no longer get access to the database. The log shows a message that there is a version problem.

I already read into some similar issues like [Postgres container crashes with `database files are incompatible with server` after container's image has been updated to the latest one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44221938/postgres-container-crashes-with-database-files-are-incompatible-with-server-af) and [Postgres container crashes with `database files are incompatible with server` after container's image has been updated to the latest one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44221938/postgres-container-crashes-with-database-files-are-incompatible-with-server-af)

and the solutions `brew postgresql-upgrade-database` did not work.

What can I do?

LOG

```
2021-10-03  [1] FATAL:  database files are incompatible with server
2021-10-03  [1] DETAIL:  The data directory was initialized by PostgreSQL version 13, which is not compatible with this version 14.0 (Debian 14.0-1.pgdg110+1).

PostgreSQL Database directory appears to contain a database; Skipping initialization
```

I also found this https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/upgrading.html but the commands didn't work. Do I need to do this in the container somehow, or what commands will work to keep it running in the container?

Comment: Do you also have something like watchtower to update the containers to their latest version? I would use `postgres:13` image (if your are getting postgres from docker.io) to stay on version 13.

Comment: I don't think I have one of those. Can you tell me what I should do?

Comment: In my case kubernetes mounted an old postgres volume which already had some data. I just had to delete the old volume to fix the issue.

Answer (score 36):

You need to update the data file to the new format with this command:

```
$ brew postgresql-upgrade-database
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This method worked great. It automatically installed postgres@13 and ran upgrade procedure.

Comment: Agree with the bot, this needs more detail. Is this not a reference to Homebrew, thus assuming that the user is on macOS? Why would you think that `brew` is the best option?

Comment: brew is no longer macos specific

Comment: this is no longer working

Answer (score 17):

I resolved it by

1. Removing the postgres image
2. Remove the volume
3. Pull the image again

Assuming you know the docker commands for above step.

Comment: What are the commands ?

Comment: @DevilCode I use `docker-compose stop` and then `docker-compose down` to remove old database and volumns.

Comment: @DevilCode 1. `docker-compose down` 2. `docker volume rm <DOCKER_VOLUME_NAME>` 3. `docker pull postgres`

Comment: Remove the volume? and lose all the data? (: Do NOT do this!

Comment: Worst advice ever. You lose all your data by doing this. Potentially losing billions of dollars at your company, getting you fired and living homeless.

Answer (score 10):

On top of the answer suggesting removing all volumes/images/containers - if you have a shared volume for the DB in `docker-compose.yml`, like:

```yaml
db:
  image: postgres:14.1-alpine
  volumes:
    - ./tmp/db:/var/lib/postgresql/data
```

You will also need to remove the postgres mapped volume data which lives in `./tmp/db`. Otherwise those conflicting files would still be there.

If you don't care about the data - you use the database for development purposes and you'll be able to re-create the db easily, just run `rm -r ./tmp/db`. Than you can just `docker-compose up` and re-create your database.

In case you care about the data, use `pg_dumpall` to dump you data before removing the files and restore after you run `docker-compose up` and your postgres service is ready again.

Answer (score 10):

In docker-compose.yml you could change

```
db-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data:rw
```

to this

```
db-data:/var/lib/postgresql@14/data:rw
```

Delete image and run

```
docker compose up -d
```

one more time

Comment: db-data:/var/lib/postgresql@15/data:rw work too)

Answer (score 6):

had a problem after running

`brew update`
`brew upgrade`

Brew upgraded `postgresql` to 14 which gave me

`psql: could not connect to server: No such file or directory Is the server running locally and accepting connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?`

I have also seen the same error you have by inspecting

`tail /usr/local/var/postgres/server.log`

I have downgraded to version 13 running

`brew uninstall postgresql`
`brew install postgresql@13`
`echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/postgresql@13/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.zshrc`

and the command I've used to start the DB again is

`pg_ctl -D /usr/local/var/postgres -l /usr/local/var/postgres/server.log start`

Answer (score 5):

Step-by-step guide to update Postgres and keep the data when using Docker.

Example below was tested while upgrading from v14 to v15 and then to v16.
Database user is `joplin`, using following `docker-compose`:

```yaml
version: '3.5'

services:
  db:
    image: postgres:15
    container_name: postgres
    volumes:
      - ./postgres-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
```

```bash
# while container is running, make a database dump
docker exec postgres pg_dumpall -U joplin > dump.sql

# stop the container
docker-compose down

# make a backup of the database data
mv postgres-data postgres-data.bak

# create a new directory to store database
mkdir postgres-data

# step up db version to `16` or `latest`
# nano ./docker-compose.yml

# update the image and start the `db` container
docker-compose pull && docker-compose up -d db

# copy recently created dump
cp ./dump.sql ./postgres-data/dump.sql

# get into the `db` container
docker exec -it postgres bash

# inside `db` container
cd /var/lib/postgresql/data/

# restore the database dump
psql -U joplin < dump.sql

# that's it, get out of the container
exit
```

Comment: Works simply enough, and I was also updating the DB of Joplin from v15 to v16. Cheers!

Answer (score 3):

I think because of the difference postgresql13 with 14 in initialization.
You can make a backup of your database before the new version, delete it and migrate database to the new version

for example in django:

```
dump: ./manage.py dumpdata -o mydata.json
load: ./manage.py loaddata mydata.json
```

> django: Of course, if you have important information, do this separately for each model and pay attention to the dependencies when loading.

Answer (score 0):

for me the database directory was in /tmp/db and since no important data was there I remove all and everything worked well ...

but if your data is important then read these:

- https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/upgrading.html
- https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/pgupgrade.html
- https://www.kostolansky.sk/posts/upgrading-to-postgresql-14/

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue after home brew update on my mac. Install v14 of postgresql.

This is what helped me:

Install old v13 binaries:

```
brew install postgresql@13
```

Backup Your old DB folder:

Initdb with new name

now use `pg_upgrade`:

```
pg_upgrade --old-datadir [Your old DB folder] --new-datadir [Your new DB folder] --old-bindir [link to old bin (v13)]
```

example:

```
pg_upgrade --old-datadir PSQ-data --new-datadir PSQ-data_new --old-bindir /usr/local/Cellar/postgresql@13/13.9/bin
```

Source for old bin You will have after install v13, just look at your terminal "Summary" after install.

After this operation just start the sever with new DB.

Answer (score -1):

I was also facing the same issue with postgres in keycloak.
Downgrading the version to 13 resolved my issue.

Answer (score -1):

I resolved it by:

1. Removing the postgres container

   `docker rm "container name"`
2. Removing the postgres image

   `docker rmi "image name"`
3. `docker-compose stop`

   `docker-compose down`
4. list all volumes

   `docker volume ls`
5. remove volume

   `docker volume rm "volume name"`

Pull the image again, assuming you know the docker commands for above step.

Comment: Ideally we want to persist whatever data is in the volume between version upgrades. I suggest considering the answers that upgrade db reusing the existing data dir.